# Getting the type of a typename or expression

Tags: c++, decltype

Consider the following example. Somewhere in my code is a name `x`. I have no idea if `x` is a type or an object (it could be both). Is there any way to get the type of `x`, i.e., `x` itself if `x` is a type or `decltype(x)` if `x` is an object?

I tried doing something as trivial as

```
decltype(int)
```

but this yields an error, since `int` is not an expression. Is there any substitute way to do this?

I would like something like:

```
typedef int l;
mydecltype(l) x; // int x;
mydecltype(x) y; // int y;
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: How did you end up with a name for which you don't know whether it's a type or an object? Where does this name come from? The problem statement doesn't make sense to me; feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I wanted to add more background but the explanation would be extremely lengthy. I am working with preprocessing directives and initialization lists on classes that inherit from other classes. In an initialization list, types and member names have the same format and I cannot get to distinguish them from the syntax.

Comment: It is definitely an XY problem, but I wouldn't be able to describe the whole problem, as it not just as simple as "I need a filename extension" :)

Comment: @akappa: He probably can't. It's bad design, obviously, but if it's some old project, his job description might be to do it anyhow.

Comment: @akappa Might be. Now, let's play this little game: You are an employee and your boss tells you to do something stupid. What exactly are you going to do? "Nah, I won't do it, that's stupid!"? Keep that in mind when answering questions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
namespace detail_typeOrName {
    struct probe {
        template <class T>
        operator T() const;
    };

    template <class T>
    T operator * (T const &, probe);

    probe operator *(probe);
}

#define mydecltype(x) decltype((x) * detail_typeOrName::probe{})
```

In this code, `(x) * detail_typeOrName::probe{}` can be parsed two ways:

- If `x` is a variable, this is `x` multiplied by the instance of `probe`.
- If `x` is a type, this is the instance of `probe` dereferenced and cast to `X`.

By carefully overloading operators, both interpretations are made valid, and both return the type we seek.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16c3a2a67ee5f0c0)

Comment: Man, you gave me goosebumps.

Comment: That's insanely clever! I'd never thought of abusing the dereference AND the cast operator in such a way. Hopefully, this won't break in the future and so have to be dealt by some unlucky, clueless maintainer...

Comment: This is almost perfect, but doesn't work for things like `mydecltype(int[1])` or `mydecltype(int(int))`

Comment: @TavianBarnes I've spent a moment trying to find a solution but I've come short. A C-style cast cannot produce a function or array rvalue. They can't be function parameters or return values lest they decay. I can't think of another part of the syntax that would be valid for both expressions and types, and allow fishing the type out in both cases.