# Why do we require “requires requires”?

Tags: c++, c++20, requires-clause, requires-expression

One of the corners of C++20 constraints is that there are certain situations in which you have to write `requires requires`. For instance, this example from [[expr.prim.req]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#prim.req-3):

> A *requires-expression* can also be used in a *requires-clause* ([temp]) as a way of writing ad hoc constraints on template arguments such as the one below:

```
template<typename T>
  requires requires (T x) { x + x; }
    T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

> The first requires introduces the *requires-clause*, and the second introduces the *requires-expression*.

What is the technical reason behind needing that second `requires` keyword? Why can't we just allow writing:

```
template<typename T>
  requires (T x) { x + x; }
    T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

<sub>(Note: please don't answer that the grammar `requires` it)</sub>

Comment: Seems `requires` might be used for method of template class, and it would be "ambiguous" `template <typename T> struct S {void f(T t) requires requires (T x) {x + x;} { t + t;} };`

Comment: Suggestion: "Is there anything that requires requires requires?". More seriously, I have a hunch that it's the same reason behind `noexcept(noexcept(...))`.

Comment: They say "_The first requires introduces the requires-clause, and the second introduces the requires-expression._", but this is not compatible with the grammar they give just above

Comment: @Quentin With `noexcept` there is ambiguity. `noexcept(f())` might mean to be `noexcept` if `f()` evaluates to true or if `f()` is `noexcept`.

Comment: @PasserBy - Well, then isn't that the same reason here? A `requires` clause can have any constexpr predicate, no?

Comment: One reason I can see for doing this is to make the parsing easier.  When the compiler sees `requires` it knows the next symbol is the requirement, so we need the additional `requires` to tell it it needs to parse that requirement as an ad-hoc requirement.

Comment: The two `requires` are homonyms in my opinion: they look the same, spell the same, smell the same, but are intrinsically different. If I were to suggest a fix, I'd suggest to rename one of them.

Comment: @StoryTeller Apparently yes, as demonstrated by NicolBolas, although to a lesser extent.

Comment: It does make sense gramatically, weirdly enough.  `add<T>()` requires a `T` that in turn requires the ability to be added to other `T`s.  So, while it looks repetitive, it makes sense if you think about it enough.  (Where "I must be addable" is the expression, and "the function needs something that must be addable" is the constraint.)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It is because the grammar requires it. It does.

A `requires` constraint does not *have to* use a `requires` expression. It can use any more-or-less arbitrary boolean constant expression. Therefore, `requires (foo)` must be a legitimate `requires` constraint.

A `requires` *expression* (that thing that tests whether certain things follow certain constraints) is a distinct construct; it's just introduced by the same keyword. `requires (foo f)` would be the beginning of a valid `requires` expression.

What you want is that if you use `requires` in a place that accepts constraints, you should be able to make a "constraint+expression" out of the `requires` clause.

So here's the question: if you put `requires (foo)` into a place that is appropriate for a requires constraint... how far does the parser have to go before it can realize that this is a requires *constraint* rather than a constraint+expression the way you want it to be?

Consider this:

```
void bar() requires (foo)
{
  //stuff
}
```

If `foo` is a type, then `(foo)` is a parameter list of a requires expression, and everything in the `{}` is not the body of the function but the body of that `requires` expression. Otherwise, `foo` is an expression in a `requires` clause.

Well, you could say that the compiler should just figure out what `foo` is first. But C++ *really* doesn't like it when the basic act of parsing a sequence of tokens requires that the compiler figure out what those identifiers mean before it can make sense of the tokens. Yes, C++ is context-sensitive, so this does happen. But the committee prefers to avoid it where possible.

So yes, it's grammar.

Comment: Does it make sense to have a parameter list with a type but without a name?

Comment: This reminds me of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462104/getting-the-type-of-a-typename-or-expression/38462523#38462523) I wrote where, as far as I can tell, the compiler cannot make sense of the code before determining what `x` is. Another example is ADL working with function templates *only if* there's a similar function template in scope ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cac6f5be4b684b1b)), otherwise parsing fails. I am under the impression that heavy context dependence is pretty common in C++.

Comment: @Quentin: There are certainly cases of context-dependency in the C++ grammar. But the committee really does try to minimize that, and they definitely don't like adding *more*.

Comment: If context is the reason, then using the same word in two contexts, is contrary to the intention.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: The use of `if` vs. `if constexpr` is not context-sensitive because telling one from the other is easily done based on the sequence of tokens. To the token sequence, an identifier is just an identifier. If the nature of that identifier determines how to parse the sequence of tokens, then you're dealing with something that is problematic in the parser. Not *impossible*, just "context sensitive". Using a keyword like this is not context sensitive in this regard because the location where you use those keywords defines the context.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: If `requires` appears after a `<>` set of template arguments or after a function parameter list, then it's a requires-clause. If `requires` appears where an expression is valid, then it is a requires-expression. This can be determined by the structure of the parse tree, not the *contents* of the parse tree (the specifics of how an identifier gets defined would be the contents of the tree).

Comment: What I mean is that then it could just as well be for example "requires constraint".

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: Sure, the requires-expression could have used a different keyword. But keywords have *huge* costs in C++, as they have the potential to break any program that used the identifier that has become a keyword. The concepts proposal already introduced two keywords: `concept` and `requires`. Introducing a third, when the second would be able to cover both cases with no grammatical issues and few user-facing problems, is just wasteful. After all, the only visual problem is that the keyword happens to be repeated twice.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk  it's bad practice anyway to inline constraints like that since you don't get subsumption as if you had written a concept. So taking an identifier for such a low use not recommended feature isn't a good idea.

Comment: In general, you can't parse C++ at all without knowing which names are types and which names are templates, so I don't like the particular example given. But ambiguities are easy to find: this is very similar to the most vexing parse.

Comment: Why can't the syntax be: `requires concept (T x) { x + x; }`? That looks like something that must have been considered.

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar: That doesn't actually fix the problem: `concept name = concept(T x) { x + x; }` is just as repetitive. The problem is that you have 3 structures but don't want to make 3 keywords.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not very proficient in the grammar-related aspects, but on the surface at least this looks a lot like the issue of space that was used to be required by the grammar in the double angle brackets of `vector<vector>>` that was 'fixed' compiler after compiler until it was essentially recognized as fixable and standardized. :-)

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar: This isn't a parsing problem; it's a repeated-keyword problem. `concept name = concept` is just as bad in terms of repetition as `requires requires`. If you think one is wrong, then the other is wrong too.

Comment: @NicolBolas To avoid repeating keywords there too, perhaps `auto name = concept` would do, or omitting the second `concept` as in `concept name = (T x) { x + x; }` ("concept lambdas").

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar: But you need to be able to use what we currently call a `requires` expression *outside* of a concept definition, so you need some syntax so that I can put a requires expression in an `if constexpr` or whatever. And you need to be able to define a `concept` that doesn't use a requires expression, so we're now back to that whole bit of having the parser assume that `(T)` means one thing or the other. The only truly good solution here is a third keyword; absent that, repeating one of the others is adequate.

Comment: I think I saw `requires requires requires` somewhere.

Answer (score 88):

The situation is exactly analogous to `noexcept(noexcept(...))`. Sure, this sounds more like a bad thing than a good thing, but let me explain. :)  We'll start with what you already know:

C++11 has "`noexcept`-clauses" and "`noexcept`-expressions." They do different things.

- A `noexcept`-clause says, "This function *should be noexcept when...* (some condition)." It goes on a function declaration, takes a boolean parameter, and causes a behavioral change in the declared function.
- A `noexcept`-expression says, "Compiler, *please tell me whether* (some expression) is noexcept." It is itself a boolean expression. It has no "side effects" on the behavior of the program — it's just asking the compiler for the answer to a yes/no question. "Is this expression noexcept?"

We *can* nest a `noexcept`-expression inside a `noexcept`-clause, but we typically consider it bad style to do so.

```
template<class T>
void incr(T t) noexcept(noexcept(++t));  // NOT SO HOT
```

It's considered better style to encapsulate the `noexcept`-expression in a type-trait.

```
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_nothrow_incrable_v =
    noexcept(++std::declval<T&>());  // BETTER, PART 1

template<class T>
void incr(T t) noexcept(is_nothrow_incrable_v<T>);  // BETTER, PART 2
```

---

C++20 has "`requires`-clauses" and "`requires`-expressions." They do different things.

- A `requires`-clause says, "This function *should participate in overload resolution when...* (some condition)." It goes on a function declaration, takes a boolean parameter, and causes a behavioral change in the declared function.
- A `requires`-expression says, "Compiler, *please tell me whether* (some set of expressions) is well-formed." It is itself a boolean expression. It has no "side effects" on the behavior of the program — it's just asking the compiler for the answer to a yes/no question. "Is this expression well-formed?"

We *can* nest a `requires`-expression inside a `requires`-clause, but we typically consider it bad style to do so.

```
template<class T>
void incr(T t) requires (requires (T t) { ++t; });  // NOT SO HOT
```

It's considered better style to encapsulate the `requires`-expression in a type-trait...

```
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_incrable_v =
    requires (T t) { ++t; };  // BETTER, PART 1

template<class T>
void incr(T t) requires is_incrable_v<T>;  // BETTER, PART 2
```

...or in a C++20 concept.

```
template<class T> concept Incrable =
    requires (T t) { ++t; };  // BETTER, PART 1

template<class T>
void incr(T t) requires Incrable<T>;  // BETTER, PART 2
```

Comment: I don't really buy this argument. `noexcept` has the problem that `noexcept(f())` could mean _either_ interpret `f()` as a boolean that we're using to set the specification _or_ check whether or not `f()` is `noexcept`. `requires` doesn't have this ambiguity because the expressions its checking for validity already have to be introduced with `{}`s. After that, the argument is basically "the grammar says so."

Comment: @Barry: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires#comment95242504_54201224). It appears the `{}` are optional.

Comment: @Eric The `{}` are not optional, that's not what that comment shows. However, that is a great comment demonstrating parsing ambiguity. Would probably accept that comment (with some explanation) as a standalone answer

Comment: `requires is_nothrow_incrable_v<T>;` should be `requires is_incrable_v<T>;`

Comment: is_incrementible??? Apparently, there is not a well-established English word for "can be incremented" but I'm guessing here that this is more correct???

Comment: Sorry, should be `is_incrementable` based on the standard's `std::incrementable_traits`, i.e. with an 'a' instead of 'i'.

Answer (score 32):

I think [cppreference's concepts page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) explains this. I can explain with "math" so to say, why this must be like this:

If you want to define a concept, you do this:

```
template<typename T>
concept Addable = requires (T x) { x + x; }; // requires-expression
```

If you want to declare a function that uses that concept, you do this:

```
template<typename T> requires Addable<T> // requires-clause, not requires-expression
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

Now if you don't want to define the concept separately, I guess all you have to do is some substitution. Take this part `requires (T x) { x + x; };` and replace the `Addable<T>` part, and you'll get:

```
template<typename T> requires requires (T x) { x + x; }
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

which explains the mechanics. The *why* is best illustrated with an example of the ambiguity that would result if we changed the language to accept a single `requires` as a shorthand for `requires requires`.

```
constexpr int x = 42;

template<class T>
void f(T) requires(T (x)) { (void)x; };

template<class T>
void g(T) requires requires(T (x)) { (void)x; };

int main(){
    g<bool>(0);
}
```

[View in Godbolt to see the compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/8nKKencKM), but note that Godbolt doesn't try the link step, which would fail in this case.

The only difference between f and g is the doubling up of 'requires'. Yet the semantic difference between f and g is enormous:

- g is just a function declaration, f is a full definition
- f accepts only bool, g accepts every type castable to void
- g shadows x with its own (superfluously parenthesized) x, but
- f casts the global x to the given type T

Obviously we wouldn't want the compiler to change one into the other automatically. This could have been solved by using a separate keyword for the two meanings of `requires`, but when possible C++ tries to evolve without introducing too many new keywords, as that breaks old programs.

Comment: I don't think is what the question is asking for. This is explaining the grammar, more or less.

Comment: But why can't you have `template<typename T> requires (T x) { x + x; }` and require that require can be both the clause and the expression?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Because you're forcing the compiler to interpret one construct as another. A `requires`-as-constraint clause does not *have to* be a `requires`-expression. That's merely one possible use of it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think there's some magical answer to this. It's just ambiguous, and the compiler has certain expectations so that it parses things correctly. Probably in the next C++ version, if they find it not to be ambiguous, they can support that.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist What I was getting at with my comment is this answer just explains the syntax.  Not what actual technical reason we have to `requires requires`.  They could have added something to the grammar to allow `template<typename T> requires (T x) { x + x; }` but they didn't.  Barry wants to know why they didn't

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think there is an answer to this question. It completely and totally adds up from a syntactic point of view (like Nicol explained). Again, maybe in the next C++ version they'll allow it and it's still not obvious whether it's unambiguous. I'm not sure Barry is asking about that though.

Comment: If we're really playing find-the-grammar-ambiguity here, OK, I'll bite. https://godbolt.org/z/i6n8kM `template<class T> void f(T) requires requires(T (x)) { (void)x; };` means something different if you remove one of the `requires`es.

Comment: Missed opportunity to use a `template template` parameter there while demonstrating `requires requires`

Comment: @Quuxplusone that example is amazing. Could you elaborate though, on what the difference is? It looks to me as if g is just a function declaration which requires the template parameter to be castable to void (so, everything matches), while f is also a definition but I'm not sure.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: I think you've got it. In [the godbolt I posted above](https://godbolt.org/z/71jhr3Ksc), the `f` with one `requires` is a definition: it is constrained on `(T(x))`, i.e. `(bool(42))` (since `T` is `bool`), i.e. `true`. Its body is `{ (void)x; }`, with a superfluous trailing `;`.  The `g` with `requires requires` is a declaration constrained on `requires (T (x)) { (void)x; }`, which is OK for all `T` (except cv-qualified `void`, and [arguably](https://godbolt.org/z/9cGconY6G) abominable types); and it has no body.

Comment: I see; godbolt apparently doesn't run the linker, so that explains why it seemed to accept calling `g<bool>(0);` from main, but that indeed fails at link-time as expected when I try it locally. Using f is of course fine, it has a definition which casts the parameter to void and does nothing with it.

Comment: [clang -Weverything](https://godbolt.org/z/8nKKencKM) helps; (1) redundant parentheses around formal parameter name in the requires clause for g - which are useful for f. (2) the function definition f has an extra trailing `;` - for g this is necessary because it is just a declaration. (3) shadowing x - we need x to be a global so that f can have this restraint that just casts the value of x to some type T and checks that the result is `true` - whereas g has a requires clause that introduces a new x, shadowing the global one. If the global x = 0, calling f is impossible.

Answer (score 21):

I found [a comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7jxq8r/does_anybody_know_why_requires_requires_was_not/drd39zt/) from Andrew Sutton (one of the Concepts authors, who implemented it in gcc) to be quite helpful in this regard, so I thought I'd just quote it here in its near-entirety:

> Not so long ago requires-expressions (the phrase introduced by the second requires) was not allowed in constraint-expressions (the phrase introduced by the first requires). It could only appear in concept definitions. In fact, this is exactly what is proposed in the section of that paper where that claim appears.
>
> However, in 2016, there was a proposal to relax that restriction [Editor's note: [P0266](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0266r2.pdf)]. Note the strikethrough of paragraph 4 in section 4 of the paper. And thus was born requires requires.
>
> To tell the truth, I had never actually implemented that restriction in GCC, so it had always been possible. I think that Walter may have discovered that and found it useful, leading to that paper.
>
> Lest anybody think that I wasn't sensitive to writing requires twice, I did spend some time trying to determine if that could be simplified. Short answer: no.
>
> The problem is that there are two grammatical constructs that need to introduced after a template parameter list: very commonly a constraint expression (like `P && Q`) and occasionally syntactic requirements (like `requires (T a) { ... }`). That's called a requires-expression.
>
> The first requires introduces the constraint. The second requires introduces the requires-expression. That's just the way the grammar composes. I don't find it confusing at all.
>
> I tried, at one point, to collapse these to a single requires. Unfortunately, that leads to some seriously difficult parsing problems. You can't easily tell, for example if a `(` after the requires denotes a nested subexpression or a parameter-list. I don't believe that there is a perfect disambiguation of those syntaxes (see the rationale for uniform initialization syntax; this problem is there too).
>
> So you make a choice: make requires introduce an expression (as it does now) or make it introduce a parameterized list of requirements.
>
> I chose the current approach because most of the time (as in nearly 100% of the time), I want something other than a requires-expression. And in the exceedingly rare case I did want a requires-expression for ad hoc constraints, I really don't mind writing the word twice. It's a an obvious indicator that I haven't developed a sufficiently sound abstraction for the template. (Because if I had, it would have a name.)
>
> I could have chosen to make the requires introduce a requires-expression. That's actually worse, because practically all of your constraints would start to look like this:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
>   requires { requires Eq<T>; }
> void f(T a, T b);
> ```
>
> Here, the 2nd requires is called a nested-requirement; it evaluates its expression (other code in the block of the requires-expression is not evaluated). I think this is way worse than the status quo. Now, you get to write requires twice everywhere.
>
> I could also have used more keywords. This is a problem in its own right---and it's not just bike shedding. There might be a way to "redistribute" keywords to avoid the duplication, but I haven't given that serious thought. But that doesn't really change the essence of the problem.

Answer (score -15):

Because you are saying that a thing A has a requirement B, and the requirement B has a requirement C.

The thing A requires B which in turn requires C.

The "requires" clause itself requires something.

You have thing A (requiring B (requiring C)).

Meh. :)

Comment: But according to the other answers, the first and second `requires` are not conceptually the same thing (one is a clause, one an expression). In fact, if I understand correctly, the two sets of `()` in `requires (requires (T x) { x + x; })` have very different meanings (the outer being optional and always containing a boolean constexpr; the inner being a mandatory part of introducing a requires expression and _not_ allowing actual expressions).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Are you saying that the requirements differ? :D