# Different behavior of the C++ gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20190 when requires clause is specified with a requires expression and without it

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

Consider these two demonstrative programs (`sizeof( unsigned long ) == sizeof( unsigned long long )`).

The first one is

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long f( unsigned long n )
    requires ( not( ( sizeof( unsigned long ) == sizeof( unsigned long long ) ) ) )
{
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f( 0 ) << '\n';
}
```

The compiler issues an error

> error: cannot call function 'long unsigned int f(long unsigned int)
>   requires !(sizeof (long unsigned int) == sizeof (long long unsigned
>   int))'

But when a requires expression is used in the requires clause like this

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long f( unsigned long n )
    requires requires { not ( sizeof( unsigned long ) == sizeof( unsigned long long ) ); }
{
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f( 0 ) << '\n';
}
```

The program compiles and run.

Is it a bug of the compiler or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. The following:

```
requires ( not( ( sizeof( unsigned long ) == sizeof( unsigned long long ) ) ) )
```

means that the function participates in overload resolution if the condition is true. In your case, the condition is false since, on your implementation, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` have the same size. Thus, the function is removed from overload resolution.

On the other hand, in the following:

```
requires requires { not ( sizeof( unsigned long ) == sizeof( unsigned long long ) ); }
```

the inner `requires` expression is the condition, and it is always true, since it is effectively just testing whether its operand is well-formed, which of course it is, regardless of whether it happens to be true or false. Since the condition is always true, the function participates in overload resolution.

Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203135/481267

Comment: Thanks. I was not attentive.:)