# Using concepts for checking if a type T has a field F

Tags: c++, reflection, c++20, c++-concepts

The following `concept` checks if a type *T* has a public field *foo*:

```
template<typename T>               
concept has_field_foo = requires { 
    T::foo;                       
};
```

Is there a way to implement a generic `concept` that would check if a type *T* has a public field *F*, something like (pseudo code... the field *F* cannot be passed like this):

```
template<typename T, typename F>               
concept has_field = requires { 
    T::F;
};
```

Comment: There is no ways to pass 'name' to template. (MACRO are generally used when we want to pass 'name').

Comment: @Jarod42 hmm, macro is an interesting idea for this! (see answer below ;-)

Comment: How many of these do you expect to do that you actually need to do, that you need a clever way of doing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking if a parameter provided has a field *F* can be easily achieved with a `requires` constraint on the function itself:

```
// accepts only parameters that have a 'foo' member
void doSomething(auto i) requires requires { i.foo; } { /* */ }
```

> <sub>For why (and when) C++20 requires `requires` `requires` see:
>   [Why do we require requires requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires)</sub>

Above method can perfectly live together with the generic case overload:

```
// the unconstrained version
void doSomething(auto i) { /* */ }
```

the correct method would be picked according to the parameter provided.

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/u35Jo3

---

To have a generic concept, we may drop in a macro to help us:

```
#define CREATE_HAS_FIELD_CONCEPT(field)     \
    template<typename T>                    \
    concept has_field_##field = requires {  \
        T::field;                           \
    }
```

We actually don't have a generic concept, but we can easily generate the required concept with above macro:

```
CREATE_HAS_FIELD_CONCEPT(foo); // creates the concept: has_field_foo
```

And use it (*instead* of the version with the *requires* above):

```
void doSomething(has_field_foo auto i) { /* */ }
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/R9nQ7Q

---

There is some value in actually creating a concept, as it can participate in partial ordering.

With a plain constraint we do not get partial ordering, as atomic constraints aren't considered equivalent, but atomic concepts are.

So the following code, based on plain constraint, fails with ambiguity:

```
void print(auto i) requires requires { i.foo; } {
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

void print(auto i) requires requires { i.moo; } {
    std::cout << "moo" << std::endl;
}

void print(auto i) requires requires { i.moo && i.foo; } {
    std::cout << "foo and moo" << std::endl;
}

struct HasFoo { int foo; };

struct HasMoo { int moo; };

struct HasFooAndMoo: HasFoo, HasMoo {};

int main() {
    print(HasFoo{});
    print(HasMoo{});
    print(HasFooAndMoo{}); // compilation error: ambiguity
                           // all 3 'print' functions are proper candidates
                           // no partial ordering for constraints, just for concepts!
}
```

while this one works as desired:

```
CREATE_HAS_FIELD_CONCEPT(foo); // creates the concept: has_field_foo
CREATE_HAS_FIELD_CONCEPT(moo); // creates the concept: has_field_moo

void print(has_field_foo auto i) {
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

void print(has_field_moo auto i) {
    std::cout << "moo" << std::endl;
}

template<class P>
concept has_fields_foo_and_moo
     = has_field_foo<P> && has_field_moo<P>;

void print(has_fields_foo_and_moo auto i) {
    std::cout << "foo and moo" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    print(HasFoo{});
    print(HasMoo{});
    print(HasFooAndMoo{}); // partial ordering for concepts rocks!
}
```

Comment: Using macros to create concepts? :(

Comment: Yeah, I understand the need here, just not sure it really worth it. It's not that hard to write the concept directly.

Comment: Anyway, great example for partial ordering, when it works and when it doesn't. Thanks! (Maybe shouldn't be hidden in an answer for a different aspect of concepts)

Comment: @YehezkelB. I will be happy if you would drop a question on partial ordering, I may try to answer it with a more simple example. This is for sure a subject that would have much confusion and misunderstandings

Comment: Worth noting is that changing the definition of the concept `has_fields_foo_and_moo` from `has_field_foo<P> && has_field_moo<P>;` to `requires { P::foo; P::moo; };` will still lead to the same ambiguity issue.