# Why are parentheses needed around negated expressions in a requires-clause?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code is an usage example of the `requires`-clause:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
  requires std::is_integral_v<T>
void take_integral(T value);
```

It accepts an expression that evalutes to a `bool` value (`std::is_integral_v<T>` in this case), and works as expected.
However, when such expression is negated with the `!` operator, it results in a compilation error:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
  requires !std::is_integral_v<T>
void take_integral(T value);
```

Diagnostic from GCC:

```
<source>:4:12: error: expression must be enclosed in parentheses
    4 |   requires !std::is_integral_v<T>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |            (                     )
Compiler returned: 1
```

Diagnostic from Clang:

```
<source>:4:12: error: parentheses are required around this expression in a requires clause
  requires !std::is_integral_v<T>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           (                     )
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Why are parentheses needed here?

Comment: See also [Why do we require requires requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54200988/2069064)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses are required because they avoid language parsing ambiguities.

Not every expression is allowed inside a `requires`-clause. In fact, the standard gives an example of how a parsing ambiguity would arise if all expressions were allowed:

> [[temp.pre]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#9.note-1)
>
> [...] The expression in a *requires-clause* uses a restricted grammar to avoid ambiguities.
>   Parentheses can be used to specify arbitrary expressions in a *requires-clause*. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<int N> requires N == sizeof new unsigned short
> int f();            // error: parentheses required around == expression
> ```
>
> — end example ]

In the above example given by the standard, a compiler couldn't possibly know whether the `sizeof` part should be parsed as a `sizeof` of the expression `new unsigned short` or `new unsigned short int`. Putting parentheses around it, like `requires (N == sizeof new unsigned short)`, solves the problem.

Comment: "parentheses around expressions [...] changes the way constraints are evaluated." No, it doesn't... outside of the obvious cases where parentheses make it valid to begin with or you're using parentheses to affect operator precedence.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Xai_8K is a short demonstration that proves that `(A || B)` "does disjunction".

Comment: It absolutely [does disjunction](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr#normal-1.1), [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/t6DFej).

Comment: @Barry I'd call that more a demonstration that `(A || B)` participates in subsumption than performs disjunction, but it certainly does indicate that `(A || B)` isn't an atomic constraint expression.

Comment: @Casey I thought that's the "doesn't do disjunction" that he was going for.

Comment: [No, they're really the same.](https://godbolt.org/z/RdcNuE).

Comment: I've removed the incorrect parts of the answer. Thanks for the heads-up.