# checking type of attribute with concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to check that an attribute of a struct/class fits to my needs with concepts, but compiler complains about.

Example:

```
struct N
{
    char value;
    auto Get() { return value; }
};

struct M
{
    int value;
    auto Get() { return value; }
};

void func3( auto n )
    requires requires
{
    //{ n.Get() } -> std::same_as<int>;
    { n.value } -> std::same_as<int>;
}
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}


void func3( auto n )
    requires requires 
{
    //{ n.Get() } -> std::same_as<char>;
    { n.value } -> std::same_as<char>;
}
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    M m;
    N n;

    func3( n );
    func3( m );
}
```

Results in a bit longer bunch of messages with ( gcc 10.1.1 )

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:202:18: error: no matching function for call to 'func3(N&)'
  202 |         func3( n );
      |                  ^
main.cpp:154:10: note: candidate: 'void func3(auto:15) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, int>];} [with auto:15 = N]'
  154 |     void func3( auto n )
      |          ^~~~~
main.cpp:154:10: note: constraints not satisfied
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void func3(auto:15) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, int>];} [with auto:15 = N]':
main.cpp:202:18:   required from here
main.cpp:154:10:   required by the constraints of 'template<class auto:15> void func3(auto:15) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, int>];}'
main.cpp:155:18:   in requirements  [with auto:15 = N]
main.cpp:158:13: note: 'n.value' does not satisfy return-type-requirement
  158 |         { n.value } -> std::same_as<int>;
      |           ~~^~~~~
cc1plus: note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail
main.cpp:165:10: note: candidate: 'void func3(auto:16) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, char>];} [with auto:16 = N]'
  165 |     void func3( auto n ) 
      |          ^~~~~
main.cpp:165:10: note: constraints not satisfied
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void func3(auto:16) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, char>];} [with auto:16 = N]':
main.cpp:202:18:   required from here
main.cpp:165:10:   required by the constraints of 'template<class auto:16> void func3(auto:16) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, char>];}'
main.cpp:166:18:   in requirements  [with auto:16 = N]
main.cpp:169:13: note: 'n.value' does not satisfy return-type-requirement
  169 |         { n.value } -> std::same_as<char>;
      |           ~~^~~~~
main.cpp:203:18: error: no matching function for call to 'func3(M&)'
  203 |         func3( m );
      |                  ^   
main.cpp:154:10: note: candidate: 'void func3(auto:15) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, int>];} [with auto:15 = M]'
  154 |     void func3( auto n ) 
      |          ^~~~~
main.cpp:154:10: note: constraints not satisfied
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void func3(auto:15) requires requires{{func3::n.value} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<<placeholder>, int>];} [with auto:15 = M]':
main.cpp:203:18:   required from here
```

The version with checking the return type of the `Get()` function works as expected. What is wrong here?

See on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/MYY84TdGj)

- clang: works as expected
- gcc 10.1.1 fails with error message
- gcc trunk: ICE! ubs :-

Update ( 12. Nov. 21 )

- gcc trunk ( version 12.x.x.) works

It seems someone has fixed the bug:
[bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96111)

Comment: Um, why is `func3` defined twice?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica `func3` is an abbreviated function template, and the two definitions are using mutually exclusive constraint expressions, but I don't recognize the syntax from C++20 concepts, thus wondering if this is Concepts TS.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Because it ones checks for int type once for char. It is only for academic purpose. I know all this can aslo be done by constexpr if and others and here especially with a simple function overload...

Comment: Yeah, they looked virtually identical sans the `char` vs `int`. Got me confused. Valid overloads then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `requires requires` syntax is Concepts TS and not Concepts C++20; citing [p0587r0: Concepts TS revisited](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0587r0.pdf): _"The resulting “`​requires requires`​” syntax is confusing and embarrassing."_. EDIT: [Or maybe they are indeed parts of C++20 Concepts](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req#3.sentence-3).

Comment: @dfri - They are indeed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That Q&A is a real gem that I had not seen before, thanks!

Comment: The "requires requires" thing can simply removed from my example by writing a concept. But to simplify the code i write it as "ad hoc" requirement which is also mentioned in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: What's "ICE! ubs"? I get a seg fault on gcc trunk. should somebody submit a bug report?

Comment: @JHBonarius: Copy/Paste error: simply the line before I use it. See last edit. Thanks

Comment: @JHBonarius: Regarding ICE -> internal compiler error, yes filled a bug report https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is actually right (when rejecting the code, not going bonkers). To quote the standard

> **[expr.prim.req.compound]/[1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.req#compound-1.3)**
>
> - If the return-type-requirement is present, then:
>
>   - Substitution of template arguments (if any) into the return-type-requirement is performed.
>   - The immediately-declared constraint ([temp.param]) of the type-constraint for `decltype((E))` shall be satisfied.

`E` is our expression, namely `n.value`.

Now, `decltype(n.value)` is `char` or `int`, that's because [`decltype` has a special rule for class member access and id expressions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.decltype#1.3). But `decltype((n.value))` is `char&` or `int&`. The value category is encoded in the type of `decltype` when dealing with a general expression (such as a parenthesized class member access).

Your example works in GCC when we amend it

```
void func3( auto n )
    requires requires
{
    //{ n.Get() } -> std::same_as<int>;
    { n.value } -> std::same_as<int&>;
}
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}


void func3( auto n )
    requires requires 
{
    //{ n.Get() } -> std::same_as<char>;
    { n.value } -> std::same_as<char&>;
}
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "decltype((E))" vs "decltype(E)" is really special :-) Thank you very much for that finding!

Answer (score 0):

As per [[expr.prim.req.compound]/1.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.compound#1.3)

> If the *return-type-requirement* is present, then:
>
> - Substitution of template arguments (if any) into the return-type-requirement is performed.
> - The immediately-declared constraint ([temp.param]) of the type-constraint for `decltype((E))` shall be satisfied. [Example: Given
>   concepts `C` and `D`,
>
>   ```
>   requires {
>     { E1 } -> C;
>     { E2 } -> D<A1, ⋯, An>;
>   };
>   ```
>
>   is equivalent to
>
>   ```
>   requires {
>     E1; requires C<decltype((E1))>;
>     E2; requires D<decltype((E2)), A1, ⋯, An>;
>   };
>   ```
>
>   (including in the case where `n` is zero). — end example
>   ]

and, from [[dcl.type.decltype]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#), particularly [[dcl.type.decltype]/1.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.5) applies

> For an expression `E`, the type denoted by `decltype(E)` is defined as
> follows:
>
> - [...]
> - (1.5) otherwise, **if `E` is an lvalue, `decltype(E)` is `T&`**, where `T` is the type of `E`;

Thus, as `value` is an `lvalue` in the `{ n.value } -> std::same_as<int>;` expression, the type constraint on the *return-type-requirement* `-> std::same_as<...>;` for the `{ n.value }` expression need to be matched for return type `int&`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct Foo {
  T value;
  auto getValue() { return value; }
};

using FooInt = Foo<int>;
using FooChar = Foo<char>;

void abbreviatedFunctionTemplate(auto n) requires requires {
  { n.value } -> std::same_as<int&>; }
{ std::cout << "int overload\n" << std::endl; }

void abbreviatedFunctionTemplate(auto n) requires requires {
  { n.getValue() } ->std::same_as<char>; }
{ std::cout << "char overload\n" << std::endl; }

int main() {
  abbreviatedFunctionTemplate(FooInt{});  // int overload
  abbreviatedFunctionTemplate(FooChar{}); // char overload
}
```