# Non-type template parameters and requires

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, non-type-template-parameter

I am learning concepts, and I can not figure out a way to restrain the value (not type) of non-type template parameter.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/d48Gv1) of code that compiles, although I wish it did not(due to failed requirement):

```
#include <cassert>

enum Bla{
    Lol, 
    Haha
};

template<Bla b>
requires requires{
    // my guess is that this just checks that this is valid expression, not
    // that it is true
    b>1; 
}
void f(){
    assert(b>1);
}

int main() {
    f<Lol>(); // compiles, not funny ;)
}
```

Note:
this is simplified example( I want "template overloading") so `static_assert` is not good for me, and I am trying to avoid `std::enable_if` since syntax is hideous.

Comment: `static_assert` would make it fail, but I guess this is just simplified example

Comment: @idclev463035818 I want it for overloading, so yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only have a boolean condition and nothing else, do this:

```
template<Bla b>
requires(b > 1)
void f() {}
```

Alternative longer syntax, if you need to check more things in the same `requires`-expression:

```
template<Bla b>
requires requires
{
    requires b > 1;
//  ^~~~~~~~
}
void f() {}
```

Comment: So top voted comment on this question found an answer? :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires

Accepting this since although cigen answer is earlier your gives a way to do more complicated stuff...

Comment: [Why stop](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7fVVXJjQSUWHC6R8) at nesting only one _requires-expression_ within another one? ;)

Comment: @dfrib You just found a GCC bug with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what bug? missing space?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yep.

Answer (score 6):

Since `f` needs to be constrained only by the value of the non-type template parameter, you can simply write a `requires` clause instead of an ad-hoc `requires requires` constraint:

```
template<Bla b>
requires (b>1) 
void f() {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6vq7rc).

You only need a `requires requires` expression if you want to do more complicated checks on the template parameter. In that case, I recommend using a named concept over an ad-hoc constraint anyway. This makes the code more readable, and allows you to reuse the concept in other places.

---

As for `assert`, it's a run-time construct, so it doesn't affect compilation in any way, assuming the expression inside the `assert` is syntactically valid. You need to use `static_assert` instead, if you want to check the template parameter at compile time:

```
static_assert(b>1);
```

Comment: @idclev463035818 is right, assert is just to show that code dies at runtime... 
Your solution is great, but now I do not get why I only need 1 requires :) , but yeah that is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl `requires requires` is a ad-hoc constraint. It's only used with requires expressions, not requires clauses. Yeah, that should probably be a different question.

Answer (score 3):

#### Constraints, requires-clause:s and requires-expression:s

You need to differentiate between a *requires-clause* and a *requires-expression*.

```
template<Bla b>
void f() requires .... {}
//                ^^^^ - constant-expression OR
//                       requires-expression
//       
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - requires-clause
```

Particularly, as per [[temp.pre]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#nt:requires-clause), the grammar for a *requires-clause* is:

> ```
> requires-clause:
>   requires constraint-logical-or-expression
> ```

where *constraint-logical-or-expression*, in turn, is a [*primary-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression), which includes [*requires-expression*:s](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim#nt:requires-expression).

#### Applied to OP:s example: constraining a non-type template parameter

In your case, you are using an ad-hoc *requires-expression* (as compared to a named constraint) as the requirement for a *requires-clause*. However, for your use case it suffices to use a *requires-clause* with a *constant-expression*. Particularly, you can restrain the value of a non-type template parameter by a constant expression in the trailing *requires-clause* of a given templated entity, say a function template:

```
enum class MyEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz
};

// Allows any specialization over MyEnum.
template<MyEnum e>
struct Wrapped {};
    
// Allows only Wrapped objects of certain
// specializations.
template<MyEnum e>
void f(Wrapped<e>) requires (e == MyEnum::Foo || e == MyEnum::Bar) {
}

int main() {
    f(Wrapped<MyEnum::Foo>{}); // OK
    f(Wrapped<MyEnum::Bar>{}); // OK
    f(Wrapped<MyEnum::Baz>{}); // Error: ... constraints not satisfied
}
```

Applied for overloading with mutually exclusive constraints:

```
// Allows any specialization over MyEnum.
template<MyEnum e>
struct Wrapped {};
    
// Overloading Wrapped specializations by 
// mutually exclusive constraints:
template<MyEnum e>
void f(Wrapped<e>) requires (e == MyEnum::Foo || e == MyEnum::Bar) {
    std::cout<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

template<MyEnum e>
void f(Wrapped<e>) requires (e == MyEnum::Baz) {
    std::cout<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

int main() {
    f(Wrapped<MyEnum::Foo>{}); // void f(Wrapped<e>) requires  e == MyEnum::Foo || e == MyEnum::Bar [with MyEnum e = MyEnum::Foo]
    f(Wrapped<MyEnum::Bar>{}); // void f(Wrapped<e>) requires  e == MyEnum::Foo || e == MyEnum::Bar [with MyEnum e = MyEnum::Bar]
    f(Wrapped<MyEnum::Baz>{}); // void f(Wrapped<e>) requires  e == MyEnum::Baz [with MyEnum e = MyEnum::Baz]
}
```