# Ad-hoc constraint requires requires requires requires?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

Suppose I'm writing a class template some of whose members are constrained on the presence *and value* of a type template parameter static constexpr data member:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    constexpr bool operator()() requires T::value { return T::value; }
    constexpr bool operator()() { return false; }
};
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(A<std::true_type>()());
static_assert(!A<std::false_type>()());
static_assert(!A<void>()());
```

MSVC and gcc accept this, but clang rejects unless I [replace](https://godbolt.org/z/bv4jM5) `requires T::value` with `requires requires { requires T::value; }`. Is this a bug in clang, or are the other compilers lax; is it the case that C++ requires requires requires requires?  What does the Standard say?

Related (well, ⅔ at least): [Why do we require requires requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a clang bug (submitted [#49513](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49513)).

It looks like clang is substituting `void` into `T::value` and deciding that because that's an invalid expression, that the constraint is *invalid*. But the rule, in [[temp.constr.atomic]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#temp.constr.atomic-3.sentence-2) is that:

> To determine if an atomic constraint is satisfied, the parameter mapping and template arguments are first substituted into its expression. If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint is not satisfied.

In this case, substitution results in an invalid type or expression, so the result of that should be that the constraint is not satisfied.

---

Note that this overload:

```cpp
constexpr bool operator()() requires T::value { return T::value; }
```

is only valid if `T::value` is a valid expression *and* evaluates to `true`. Which makes it equivalent to this:

```cpp
constexpr bool operator()() requires T::value { return true; }
```

Which is fine in this case, since you're returning `false` in the other case anyway, so there's no reason to distinguish `T::value` exists but is `false` from `T::value` does not exist.

But thought it was worth clarifying anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, I may have oversimplified the example. It makes a little more sense with (a lot of) context.

Comment: This bug in Clang is fixed in trunk by now: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/48857