# Why noexcept is used twice for global swap function

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

I'm trying to understand `noexcept`. I came to know global swap function is generally specified like this

```
void swap (T& x, T& y) noexcept(noexcept(x.swap(y)))
{
   x.swap(y);
}
```

I want to understand why noexcept specification is `noexcept(noexcept(x.swap(y)))` but not `noexcept(x.swap(y))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are two kinds of usage of [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/noexcept).

The [noexcept operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) used in `noexcept(x.swap(y))` would return `true` if `x.swap(y)` is declared not to throw, and `false` otherwise.

> It can be used within a function template's noexcept specifier to declare that the function will throw exceptions for some types but not others.

The [noexcept specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) is used to specify whether a function could throw exceptions. `noexcept(noexcept(x.swap(y)))` specifies `swap` throws or not according to the result of `noexcept(x.swap(y))`; i.e. whether `swap` could throw or not depends on whether `x.swap(y)` could throw or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware noexcept keyword had two roles, one as a specifier and one as an operator. Now its clear!

Comment: @Infinity In C++20 [we'll have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires) something similar for `requires`.