# Does the `requires` nested in a requires-expression introduce a requires-clause?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-clause

From questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires), from [C++20 - The Complete Guide](https://leanpub.com/cpp20), and even from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/requires), my understanding is that the keyword `requires` can do one of 2 things only:

- introduce a [*requires-clause*](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.temp#:requires-clause)
- introduce a [*requires-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:requires-expression)

and I also think I've understand more or less what they are for, thanks to linked sources.

However, I'm puzzled by the use of `requires` inside a [*requires-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:requires-expression), e.g.

```cpp
template<typename T>
… requires {
  requires std::is_const_v<T>;
}
```

From [the standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/), I read that a [*requires-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:requires-expression) (e.g. the one introduced by the first `requires` in the snippet above) must have a [*requirement-body*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:requirement-body), which must in turn be a `{ requirement-seq }`, i.e. something between curly braces, which is not the case of `std::is_const_v<T>;`, from which I deduce that `requires std::is_const_v<T>;` is a [*requires-clause*](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.temp#:requires-clause), that should look like this

> `requires` [*constraint-logical-or-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:constraint-logical-or-expression)

However, [[expr.prim.req.nested]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.nested) tells me that a [*nested-requirement*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:nested-requirement) looks like this:

> `requires` [*constraint-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#nt:constraint-expression);

So maybe use of `requires` nested in a [*requires-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:requires-expression) is not a [*requires-clause*](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.temp#:requires-clause)?

If it is, I think the difference between the two quoted grammars above should mean that [*nested-requirement*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:nested-requirement)s are a subset of [*requires-clause*](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.temp#:requires-clause)s, in which case I should be able to see, following the various cross-references, that a [*constraint-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#nt:constraint-expression) is a [*constraint-logical-or-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:constraint-logical-or-expression) but not viceversa. Now I see that

- a [*constraint-logical-or-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:constraint-logical-or-expression) can be a [*primary-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression),
- which can be in turn an `( expression )`
- [expression](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#nt:expression) (***unparenthesized***) can be an [*assignment-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#nt:assignment-expression)
- which can be a [*conditional-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#nt:conditional-expression)
- which can be a [*logical-or-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.or#nt:logical-or-expression)

And a [*constraint-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#nt:constraint-expression) is a [*logical-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.or#nt:logical-or-expression) too.

But what I don't understand is where the parenthesis are gone.

Comment: from the linked `require-expression` it looks like it just a `nested-requirement`. I don't quite get the rest of question tbh.

Comment: `requires-expression` -> `requires requirement-parameter-list(opt) requirement-body` -> `requires requirement-body` -> `requires {requirement-seq}` -> `requires {requirement}` -> **`requires {nested-requirement}` -> `requires {requires constraint-expression;}`**

Comment: @appleapple, not sure if it helps, but I had made a typo in the paragraph before the bullet list. Fixed now.

Comment: To use your notation, I'm saying that, on the one hand, `requires !std::is_const_v<T>;` is a `nested-requirement` -> `requires constraint-expression;` -> `requires logical-or-expression;`; on the other hand, `requires-clause` -> `requires constraint-logical-or-expression` -> `requires constraint-logical-and-expression` -> `requires primary-expression` -> `requires ( expression )` -> `requires ( assignment-expression )` -> `requires ( conditional-expression )` -> `requires ( logical-or-expression )`.

Comment: So if it is true that `requires !std::is_const_v<T>;` is a `nested-requirement`, it should have the form of `requires logical-or-expression;`, whereas if it is a `requires-clause`, it should have the form of `requires ( logtical-or-expression )`. I think it is a `requires-clause` (isn't it?) and, more precisely, a `nested-requirement`. If that's the case, I see a mismatch between it being `requires ( logical-or-expression )` and also a `requires logical-or-expression;`.

Comment: well it doesn't have `()` shows it cannot derived from that lexical group (i.e. it's not (at least directly) a `require-clause`). just like a `[i]` can both be a beginning of lambda or subscript operator.

Comment: @‌Enlico fwiw, as you linked, the `require-clause` (with the form `requires ( expression )`)  is for `template<typename T>
requires (!std::is_const_v<T>)
void foo(){}`

Comment: @appleapple, I've removed the `!` as it just adds a complication that my question is not about.

Comment: @appleapple, I don't understand the first comment with the `()`.

Comment: @appleapple, whether `[i]` is the beginning of a lambda or subscript-based indexing, the square brackets are there. But `requires std::is_const_v<T>;` is valid in the snippet in my question, and it looks to me like it has not the form of a `requires-clause`, because it lacks the parenthesis. I must be wrong, and I'd like to understand how.

Comment: yes, it's not the best example. I was trying to make the point that they're just different, you don't parse a program by see just part of it.

Comment: Apparently (from the answer) my understanding that a _nested-requirement_ is a _requires-clause_ is wrong.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to answer this. Of course a nested `requires ...;` is neither a *requires-clause* nor a *requires-expression*. You seem to have a misunderstand of how the grammar works. You can't just take a random definition from the middle of the grammar and match it against a random piece of code (like you do in the second part of the question). You must start with [*translation-unit*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#nt:translation-unit) (the top-level symbol of the grammar) and match it to the whole source file, gradually descending to the desired element.

Comment: @Enlico well, it's not a `require-expression` either, and actually it can also be subpart of `require-clause` (within sub `require-expression`).

Comment: for example `template<typename T>
requires requires{ requires !std::is_const_v<T>; }
void foo(){}`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I'm not taking any random piece from anywhere. My question starts with _my understanding is that the keyword `requires` can do one of 2 things only: introduce a requires-clause, introduce a requires-expression_. If that's wrong in the first place (and apparently it is), is there any reason to keep reading the rest of the question? Anything can follow from wrong assumptions. So I guess I didn't need to take anything random from the middle of anywhere, no?

Comment: What I'm saying is, you took `requires std::is_const_v<T>;`, and tried to match it against *requires-clause*. But you can't do that. Even if you matched it successfully, it wouldn't mean anything. You need to start at the whole translation unit and match it against *translation-unit*, and then descend recursively.

Comment: _Even if you matched it successfully, it wouldn't mean anything._ What do you mean by "matching"? Text-matching? If so, yes, ok, but the mistake is simply in the hypothesis that `requires` could introduce 1 of 2 things only. I wouldn't even have tried matching it if I knew it could introduce a 3rd thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A requires-clause is a grammatical construct that is only introduced by a [declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl) ([only for templated functions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl#4)), [function definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def#general-1), [class member declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem), [template header](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#1), or [lambda syntax](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda). You can see that from the grammar.

The only way to put a requires-clause inside a requires-expression is to smuggle it in via a lambda. But then, the clause applies just to that lambda.

A nested-requirement is not a requires-clause, neither grammatically nor semantically. The key difference is that a requires-clause is required to only be a series of primary expressions merged by `&&` and `||`. This is important for being able to decompose a requires-clause down into a series of atomic constraints. Nested-requirements are able to do more because a nested requirement is itself a single atomic constraint.

Put more simply, the requires-clause [defines a constraint](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#general-1.sentence-1):

> A constraint is a sequence of logical operations and operands that specifies requirements on template arguments.

A nested-requirement is itself an atomic constraint.

Comment: If a _nested-requirement_ (which is introduced via `requires`) is not a _requires-clause_, then is it a _requires-expression_ (which is introduced by `requires` too)? If so, how comes it lacks the `{}` bit? If not, then should I deduce that `requires` can introduce 3 things (_requires-expression_, _requires-clause_, _nested-requirement_),  and not 2 (_requires-expression_, _requires-clause_)?

Comment: @Enlico: It is a nested-requirement. That's the name of the grammatical construct. It is neither a nested-expression nor a requires-clause. You're trying to apply formal language to answers and questions that were not themselves using formal language.

Comment: I've understood that, and thank you for explaining. I'm just asking confirmation that this means that `requires` can be the beginning of 3 things. Or maybe there's a 4th grammatical construct starting with `requires`?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard never says `requires` can **only** be the beginning of `requires-clause` and `requires-expression`. It can also be the beginning of `nested-requirement`, which is one of the four types of requirements in the requirement body for `requires-expression`.

Althrough `nested-requirement` may looks like `requires-clause` in grammar, they are not the same. For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept CF = false;

template <typename T>
void foo()
    requires // requires clause
    requires // requires expression
{
    requires !CF<T>; // nested requirement
}
{}

template <typename T>
void bar()
    requires !CF<T> // invalid requires clause
{}
```

I'm not sure whether the keyword page for `requires` on cppreference is correct (maybe incomplete?). `requires-clause` and `nested-requirement` are totally different things. I think it's OK to say `requires` can be the beginning of 3 things. If you want to find all the usages for a keyword, I think the best way is to read the Index page of the C++ standard.