# C++ 'requires' with type requirement in class won't compile

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-clause, requires-expression

This code won't compile on any C++ complaint compiler (Clang, GCC, MSVC):

```
template<typename T>    
    requires(T t) { typename T::name; }
class MyVector
{    
};
```

The error(s):

```
 --- Clang ----
    <source>:9:14: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
        requires(T t) { typename T::name; }
                 ^
    <source>:8:19: note: declared here
    template<typename T>    
                      ^
 --- GCC ----
    <source>:9:16: error: expected primary-expression before 't'
        9 |     requires(T t) { typename T::name; }

 --- MSVC ----
    <source>(9): error C2760: syntax error: 't' was unexpected here; expected ')'
    <source>(9): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

But this will:

```
template<typename T>    
        requires std::is_integral_v<T>   &&
        requires(T t) { typename T::name; }
class MyVector{};
```

Interestingly, this will also compile fine!

```
 template<typename T>    
            requires true   &&
            requires(T t) { typename T::name; }
 class MyVector{};
```

I am aware `concept` can be used instead, but was trying `requires` alone.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requires(T t) { typename T::name; }` is a *requires-expression*.

However under the template head of a template declaration you can (optionally) put only a *requires-clause*, not a *requires-expression*.

A *requires-clause* also uses the `requires` keyword, but in a distinct meaning from that of a *requires-expression*. A *requires-clause* has the form `requires E` where `E` is an expression formed by conjunction/disjunction of constraint expressions. An atomic constraint can be a *requires-expression* though:

```
template<typename T>    
requires requires(T t) { typename T::name; }
```

---

In both

```
template<typename T>    
requires std::is_integral_v<T>   &&
    requires(T t) { typename T::name; }
```

and

```
template<typename T>    
requires true   &&
    requires(T t) { typename T::name; }
```

you are applying the correct syntax. The first `requires` introduces the *requires-clause*, the `&&` is a conjunction between individual constraint expression and the second `requires` introduces a *requires-expression* as one of the constraint expressions.