# C++ requires the Template variadic number to less than N, but failed

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I wanted to constrain the number of the template type to be less than 3.  I expected `F(1,2,3)` to not compile but it actually did and printed 3.

```
template <typename ...Ts>
concept LessThan3 = requires {
  sizeof...(Ts) < 3;
};

template <typename... Ts>
requires LessThan3<Ts...>
void F(Ts... ts) {
  cout << sizeof...(ts);
};

int main() {
  F(1, 2, 3);  // Compile
}
```

However, if I explicitly put the `sizeof...(Ts) < 3` in the function declaration, `F(1,2,3)` won't compile, work as expected.

```
template <typename... Ts>
requires(sizeof...(Ts) < 3) void F(Ts... ts) {
void F(Ts... ts) {
  cout << sizeof...(ts);
};
// F(1,2,3) doesn't compile, expected.
```

What's the correct way of `require` a concept?

Comment: The *requirement-seq* enclosed in brackets are not described to be Boolean predicates, but satisfiable syntax constraints. [Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires)

Comment: I'll share a question which really helps clearing up these `requires` things for me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54200988/3966456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof...(Ts) < 3` itself does nothing, the computed result is ignored. It should be

```
template <typename ...Ts>
concept LessThan3 = requires {
  requires sizeof...(Ts) < 3;
};
```

Similar: `N < 3` vs. `static_assert(N < 3)`.

Comment: No need for double `requires`, `LessThan3=(sizeof...(Ts)<3)` should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

To add on to others' answers, you can actually simplify your concept requirement by doing this:

```
template <size_t Size>
concept LessThan3 = (Size < 3);

template <typename... Ts>
    requires LessThan3<(sizeof...(Ts))>
void F(Ts... ts) {
  std::cout << sizeof...(ts);
};
```

You would see that if you passed two parameters, it works. But, if greater than two, it has a compilation error that says it doesn't satisfy LessThan3.