# Template base-name substitution

Tags: c++, templates

I wish to pass an allocator type to a class, without needing the client to specify the types of its members.

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<typename STRALLOC, typename INTALLOC>
struct Thing {
    std::vector<std::string, STRALLOC> string_content;
    std::vector<int,         INTALLOC> int_content;
};

int main() {
    Thing<std::allocator<std::string>, std::allocator<int>> heapStuff;
    Thing<std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::string>, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>> polyStuff;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to simply use something like the following:

```
template<typename ALLOC>
struct Thing {
    std::vector<std::string, ALLOC<std::string> string_content;
    std::vector<int,         ALLOC<int> int_content;
};

int main() {
    Thing<std::allocator> heapStuff;
    Thing<std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator> polyStuff;
    return 0;
}
```

However I cannot do this because e.g. `std::allocator` is not a typename without its template parameter.

Is there any wizardry to make this possible?

[edit]

This actually appears to be simple:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<template<class> typename ALLOCATOR>
struct Thing {
    std::vector<std::string, ALLOCATOR<std::string>> string_content;
    std::vector<int,         ALLOCATOR<int>> int_content;
};

int main() {
    Thing<std::allocator> heapStuff;
    Thing<std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator> polyStuff;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: template template parameters is the keyword

Comment: Ah, C++ Weekly Episode 368

Comment: Weekly Episode #265: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54200988/5470596 _"Why do we require requires requires?"_

Comment: The specific example that is almost equivalent to this is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337689/1607937

Comment: please do not edit an answer into the question. Even as duplicate imho this question was a good one. Sometimes duplciates survive as signposts to the question that has the answers. However, once you include the answer inside the quesiton, the question is somewhat pointless.