# C++ class template taking either type or non-type

Tags: c++, templates

I see a few similar questions, but they don't seem to get at this.

I can overload a function on a template:

```
template <typename T> void foo(); // Called as e.g., foo<int>();
template <std::size_t I> void foo(); // Called as e.g., foo<2>();
```

Is there a way to do something similar with a class, where I can have either `MyClass<int>` or `MyClass<2>`?

I can't see a way to do it. (My real goal is to have a `static constexpr` instance of an invokable that acts like `std::get`. Whereas `std::get` is templated on its "indexing" parameter and on the argument type, I'd like to make one that is invokable on its own, so `myns::get<2>` and `myns::get<int>` are both invokable and when invoked act like `std::get<2>(tup)` and `std::get<int>(tup)` respectively.

Naively you'd hope something like this would work, but the `auto` is a type:

```
template <auto IndOrType>
constexpr auto get = [](auto&& tup) {
    return std::get<IndOrType>(std::forward<decltype(tup)>(tup));
};
```

I can make a getter function that returns a lambda, but then it's called with `()` as in `myns::get<2>()(tup)` or `myns::get<int>()(tup)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specialize the class using the helper type `std::integral_constant<int,N>`. Though unfortunately this doesn't exactly allow the `MyClass<2>` syntax:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
};

template<int N>
using ic = std::integral_constant<int,N>;

template<int N>
class MyClass<ic<N>>
{

};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> a;
    MyClass<ic<2>> b;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/84xoE1Yd4

Comment: Right. If only there were a way to make `2` implicitly convert to `ic<2>` in that context...

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping it might automatically match against the specialization, but alas.

Comment: BTW I'm not entirely sure of your intended use case. But couldn't perhaps an overloaded function `makeMyClass` work? Instead of directly naming the type, let a overloaded function do the specialization to either version of MyClass.

Comment: I was really just hoping to syntactically do `auto f = get<X>; f(t);` and have that act like `std::get<X>(t);`, which seems natural. It seems so simple, yet to do that, I found myself feeling like it might be possible, so I figured it was a good question for SO.

Comment: It seems that function templates are the only thing that can be overloaded on leading template parameter, so it may ultimately not be possible to overload like this.

Comment: You could still do like `std::get`, but add a third overload: `get(void)` that returns the lambda you mentioned. Then you have the regular use of `get`, as well as `auto f = myns::get(); f(t);`.

Comment: Yeah, short of a way to put either a type or a non-type template parameter in the same place, I think that's the best solution.

Comment: I just saw this SO answer pointing to a proposal to add truly universal template parameters. I think that would solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70377784/874660 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1985r0.pdf

Comment: OK, P1985 does address this. Here's it working in the Circle C++ compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/cfr4jjTcz